# Force OpenSSH server to accept nonexistent usernames?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd, pam

Can sshd be configured to accept a nonexistent username and log in as a predefined user, such as guest?

For example, if I enter `ssh nxuser123@localhost`, sshd should save "nxuser123" in an environment variable and log into the host as "guest."

I noticed a similar question from a few years ago, but it was never properly answered: [Can I get OpenSSH's sshd to accept a login for a non-existent user?](https://superuser.com/questions/470417/can-i-get-opensshs-sshd-to-accept-a-login-for-a-non-existent-user)

I do not want to create the nonexistent user accounts as someone suggested in an answer to the above question.

Comment: No, you need to whitelist the names somewhere else to properly accept them (LDAP, nsswitch.conf). Allowing login to all non-existent users is very dangerous.

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: I understand that allowing non-existent users to access the server would be dangerous, but that isn't the goal in this case. I'm attempting to use OpenSSH server as a "wrapper" that executes a program upon connection with `ForceCommand`.

Comment: you can ask a new question for that. you might get help.